# how to use a quotation mark in an sql find / replace command where " is the thing to be replaced?

Tags: sql, mysql, replace

Here's what I tried:

```
UPDATE `main` SET Practice = replace(Practice,""","");
```

I have stray quotation marks in column Practice of table main that I am trying to do a mass execution on. But, all I get are syntax error messages. This syntax has worked for other such intentional carnage, but not for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To specify a literal quote character, escape it using the standard `\` character:

```
UPDATE `main` SET Practice = replace(Practice,"\"","");
```

You can also use single quotes to avoid the need to use the escape character:

```
UPDATE `main` SET Practice = replace(Practice,'"','');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use single quotes:

```
UPDATE `main` SET Practice = REPLACE(Practice, '"', '');
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you need `""""` or `"\""` depending on the language, instead of `"""`?

Comment: MySQL happens to accept either doubling or backslashing by the way.